# PLP Router Link encodes Product Code with slash / to %2F, Getting 404 on PDP

Tags: angular, encoding, router, spartacus-storefront

If we have product codes with "/", it gets encoded to "%2F".

**Example Encoded URL:** domain.com/baseSite/p/AB%2FC
When this encoded URL is directly accessed or bookmarked, we are getting HTTP 404. Seems like the Spartacus was not able to map the route. Please advise.

Product Code (width slash): AB/C

Template html:

```
      <a [routerLink]="{ cxRoute: 'product', params: product } | cxUrl">
```

Generated HTML

```
<a ng-reflect-router-link="/,p,AB/C" href="/<baseSiteId>/p/AB%2FC">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Angular issue as opposed to Spartacus. Params should be passed to `[routerLink]` as an array rather than a literal string.

For example:

```
<a [routerLink]="{ cxRoute: 'product', params: ['my', 'slashy', 'product'] } | cxUrl">
```

This is how angular handles params using router link: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: This is how it looks like in the template.html  <a [routerLink]="{ cxRoute: 'product', params: product } | cxUrl">

The generated URL converts %2F for '/' which makes the routing break for product codes with '/' or special character. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Assuming product is a string, try putting `product` in brackets to make it an array like `[product]`.

eg. `<a [routerLink]="{ cxRoute: 'product', params: [product] } | cxUrl">`

Comment: Did not work Caine. By the way, "product" is an object. I tried to change it to product.code (this is the string).

<a [routerLink]="{ cxRoute: 'product', params: [product.code] } | cxUrl">

The generated HTML did not even include the product code anymore ==> link="/" href="/<baseSite>/"